# Update listView and Adapter after update Database

Tags: android, database, android-studio, listview, sql-update

I have external Database and I have to update database from activity with method of update `

```
public long updateInfo(ModelInsertInfo modelInsertInfo) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID,modelInsertInfo.getId());
    values.put(KEY_yearWater, modelInsertInfo.getYearWater());
    values.put(KEY_MonthWater, modelInsertInfo.getMonthWater());
    values.put(KEY_DayWater, modelInsertInfo.getDayWater());
    values.put(KEY_HourWater, modelInsertInfo.getHourWater());
    values.put(KEY_MinWater, modelInsertInfo.getMinWater());
    return db.update(TABLE_Insert_Info, values, "" + KEY_ID + "= " + 
    modelInsertInfo.getId() + "", null);
}
```

database updated but nothing change in list or in activity.
My Inner activity get id from click on `listview` item and I updated database from inner activity.

I used this

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    adapterListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.invalidateViews();
    clearPref();
}
```

And this in the `onCreate()`

```
adapterListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapterListView.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
listView.invalidateViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I recommend using RecyclerView instead of ListView. 
Secondly you may delete updating methods from onCreate() and onResume() callbacks, and just do setting updating items to RecyclerView adapter and notifyDataSetChanged. Use getter from databese after database updating for updating RecyclerView items.

RecyclerView documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

After updating database either update list by adding new value or clear list and get value from database to the list. and then give adapterListView.notifyDataSetChanged();